# Proof that 1-P(B|C)=P(~B|C). Is everything correct?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, conditional-probability

Proof:

Suppose we have a set of students. Different students study different subjects, with some of them studing several subjects at once. Suppose among many other subjects we have Biology and Chemistry. Then $P(B|C)$ would be probability of selecting a Biology student out of set of Chemistry students.

Now we need to ask ourselves: what would be the complement of event "selecting a Biology student out of set of Chemistry students"?. Remember that we select a Biology student out of set of Chemistry students, NOT from all students. In other words, our sample space shrunk to the size of the set of Chemistry students. The complement event would be selecting a Chemistry student who does NOT study Biology (although the person can study other subjects along with Chemistry).

The probability of selecting such person out of set of Chemistry students can be written as $P(\tilde B|C)$.

Thus $1-P(B|C)=P(\tilde B|C)$ because $P(B|C)$ and $P(\tilde B|C)$ are complements of each other.

Comment: It's a wall of text, so a bit difficult to read, but what you say seems reasonble. Please consider breaking it into paragraphs.

Comment: $P(B\mid C)$ and $P(\sim B\mid C)$ are not complements themselves but are  probabilities (not according to $P(-)$ but according to $P(-\mid C)$) of the sets $B$ and $\sim B$ which are complements of each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your are correct, and the proof is rather simple (not requiring the wall of text you wrote :)

$$\begin{align}P(\neg B|C)&=\frac{P(\neg B \land C)}{P(C)} &\text{by definition}
\\&= \frac{P(C) - P(B\land C)}{P(C)} & \text{Because $B\land C$ and $\neg B\land C$ form a partition of $C$}
\\&=\frac{P(C)}{P(C)}-\frac{P(B\land C)}{P(C)}&\text{Algebraic manipulation}
\\&=1-P(B|C)&\text{by definition}\end{align}$$

---

*Note*: I assume here that $P(C)>0$, i.e. that $C$ is not an impossible event. Things can get complicated quickly if we look at a more general solution.

Comment: Wait, how did you go from P(~B∩C) to P(C)-P(B∩C)?

Comment: And what is "partition of C"?

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram to verify the fact that $P(B^c\cap C) = P(C) - P(B\cap C)$

Comment: OK, it makes sense now.

Comment: @user161005 If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, then $P(A\lor B) = P(A)+P(B)$. In my case, I used the fact that $\neg B\land C$ and $B\land C$ are mutually exclusive, ant that $(\neg B\land C)\lor(B\land C) = C$.

Comment: What if $P(C)=0$?  This formula only works when $P(C)\not=0$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Based on the level of the question, I decided to go with the "simple" version of the answer - that is, to not go into the full probabilistic or measure-theoretic implications of what a conditional probability *really* is - as that would probably leave OP confused, rather than informed. I do agree that I should mention this somewhere (I added a note commenting on this at the end of my answer)

Comment: If $P(C)=0$, then $P(B|C)$ isn't even defined. Also, $P(C)=0$ doesn't mean $C$ is impossible.

Comment: @user2357112 Not entirely true. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and both uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, then $P(X\geq 0.5|Y=1)$ is defined, and is $0.5$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ denote a probability space and let $C\in\mathcal A$ with $P(C)>0$

Then the function $P(-\mid C):\mathcal A\to\mathbb R$ is a  *probability measure* on measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$.

It is prescribed by $A\mapsto P(A\cap C)/P(C)$ and it is not difficult to show that this is indeed a probability measure on measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$.

---

For *every* probability measure $\mu$ it is true that: $$1-\mu(B)=\mu(B^{\complement})\text{ for every set }B\text{ in the domain of }\mu$$

So what is said above ensures that indeed:$$1-P(B\mid C)=P(B^{\complement}\mid C)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is correct. Here is another way you could think about it:

$$P(B^c|C) =\frac{P(B^c\cap C)}{P(C)}$$
$$=\frac{P(C)-P(B\cap C)}{P(C)}$$
$$=1-P(B|C)$$

Draw a Venn diagram to see that $P(B^c \cap C) = P(C)-P(B\cap C)$.